# How to generate REGEX for a pattern

Tags: regular-expressions

I am validating a string with a REGEX pattern.

`'12345.12345'`. The pattern should come NUMBER . NUMBER.

I was trying with `'[\\D]',` but it will not be OK, because I want to use `'.'`.

Any help?

Comment: `\D` is a class for everything that's NOT a digit while `\d` is a class for characters that ARE digits. The period or "dot" needs to be escaped as in `\.`, otherwise a dot will search to match any character except for a line break.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work and results in true:

```
String s = '1234.1234';
String pat = '^\\d*\\.?\\d*$';
Matcher m = pattern.compile(pat).matcher(s);
system.debug(logginglevel.error,m.matches());
```

As expected this would result in false:

```
String s = 'A1234.1234';
String pat = '^\\d*\\.?\\d*$';
Matcher m = pattern.compile(pat).matcher(s);
system.debug(logginglevel.error,m.matches());
```

I am not an expert on Regex so there may be better ways but the above at least works.

You can test regex patterns at the online regex debugger http:// www.regex101.com

It is very helpful at explaining the reggae as well. Keep in mind the '\' is escaped above with a double '\' so in the website only use one '\'

Comment: You may want to add a $ at the end to specify the digits as the end of the text.

Comment: @MikeChale -Done and updated